# Issues when trying to connect with AWS document db from local Node.js app in my windows local machine

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-documentdb

I have setup aws document DB and able connect to it through ec2 using compass and studio 3T.
But i am unable to connect to cluster using Node.Js

NodeJs Code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var username = 'DBusername';
  var password = 'DBpassword';
  var client = MongoClient.connect(
    `mongodb://root:<DBpassword>@<clusterendpoint>:27017/<DBname>?tls=true`,
    {
      tlsCAFile: `./rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`,
    },
    function (err, client) {
      if (err) throw err;
  
      //Specify the database to be used
      db = client.db('DBname');
  
      //Specify the collection to be used
     
    }
  );

   
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

i tried creating ssh tunnel through nodejs code and then executing this. still it gave a timeout. Even tried creating seperate ssh connection for port forwarding and then trying to connect using localhost url , it didnt work too. Can someone help on this

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect from your local machine via ssh tunnel, then you need specify tlsAllowInvalidHostnames option in the uri.
Your uri should be something like this: `mongodb://root:<DBpassword>@localhost:27017/<DBname>?tls=true&tlsAllowInvalidHostnames&retryWrites=false`